# Convert google form responses from Excel values into pdf images

Tags: google-forms

I have a google doc page that is a "slider" quiz. So for example, people rate themselves based on a scale on how comfortable they are with say Microsoft Word (0=weak to 5= strong). Then powerpoint, etc.
These responses are submitted and saved in an excel google doc "responses.csv". 
Based on the response per column, I want to use the "document studio" add-on, for which I select "google slide" as the option. So it makes me a google slide from the responses.

But I want to make a function that pulls the replies in values 1-5 and gives me an image, so I made an if(A1=1, "drive.google.com/1.jpg", A1=2, "drive.google.com/2.jpg"). Then I referenced the column "image-slider-1".

However, the image is not pulling up in the google slide. And I don't know why. I tried to reference the slider value and import an image from google docs.

Comment: FYI google docs is not related to Excel, and definitely not to VBA.

Comment: this is a google excel doc...

Comment: Google sheets and Excel are two different companies and products.  Simple spreadsheet formulas may work similarly in both, but beyond that they diverge pretty quickly.